# How to minimize a function following an asymptotic pattern?

Tags: asymptotics, nonlinear-optimization, regression, linear-regression

When running simulation of data following a linear function (with noise) with python, I can find that the linear model gives the best fit according to the standard error of the regression:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

# setting the independent variable
lim_sup = 100
x = np.arange(1, lim_sup, 1)
x_reg = x.reshape(99,1)

# setting the dependent variable as a linear function
# of the independent variable with some added noise
error = np.random.normal(0, 5, lim_sup - 1)
y_test_lin = 3 * x + error

# finding the best fit for the data with
# a linear regression model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x_reg, y_test_lin)

# Predicting the data with the coefficient and intercept
# found with the linear regression
y_pred_lin = x * regr.coef_ + regr.intercept_

# Predicting the data with the linear model (the one just
# found) as well as a logarithmic and asymptotic model
y_pred_1 = y_pred_lin
y_pred_2 = 50 * np.log(x)
y_pred_3 = 100 * np.arctan(x)

# Compare the goodness of fit of those different models with
# the standard error of the regression
root_mean_squared_error_pred_1 = sqrt(sum((y_pred_1 - y_test_lin) ** 2) / lim_sup)
print("Root Mean Squared Error: ", root_mean_squared_error_pred_1)
```

Root Mean Squared Error:  4.475865763351861

```
root_mean_squared_error_pred_2 = sqrt(sum((y_pred_2 - y_test_lin) ** 2) / lim_sup)
print("Root Mean Squared Error: ", root_mean_squared_error_pred_2)
```

Root Mean Squared Error:  58.73409708967253

```
root_mean_squared_error_pred_3 = sqrt(sum((y_pred_3 - y_test_lin) ** 2) / lim_sup)
print("Root Mean Squared Error: ", root_mean_squared_error_pred_3)
```

Root Mean Squared Error:  81.80226281199442

When running simulation of data following a logarithmic function (with noise) with python, after linearizing the data, I can find that the linear model gives the best fit according to the standard error of the regression:

```
# setting the dependent variable as a exponential function
# of the independent variable with some added noise
y_test_exp = exp(x) + exp(error)

# linearize the exponential data by computing its logarithm
y_test_lin = log(y_test_exp)

# finding the best fit for the data with
# a linear regression model
regr.fit(x_reg, y_test_lin)

# Predicting the data with the coefficient and intercept
# found with the linear regression
y_pred_lin = x * regr.coef_ + regr.intercept_

# Predicting the data with the linear model (the one just
# found) as well as an logarithmic asymptotic model
y_pred_1 = y_pred_lin
y_pred_2 = 100 * np.arctan(x)

root_mean_squared_error_pred_1 = sqrt(sum((y_pred_1 - y_test_lin) ** 2) / lim_sup)
print("Root Mean Squared Error: ", root_mean_squared_error_pred_1)
```

Root Mean Squared Error:  0.1331147098437333

```
root_mean_squared_error_pred_2 = sqrt(sum((y_pred_2 - y_test_lin) ** 2) / lim_sup)
print("Root Mean Squared Error: ", root_mean_squared_error_pred_2)
```

Root Mean Squared Error:  104.5638974518184

Now I would like to minimize I'm trying to minimize a function that could fit data following an asymptotic function as the following:

```
y_test_exp = 100 * np.arctan(x)
```

How could it be done? Is there a way to linearise the data? If not is there an alternative?

Comment: Are you expecting people on MSE to read your code???

Comment: As written, this question would be better suited for StackOverflow. Even then, it has too many extraneous details. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you have been working with have the form $$y=f(a,b,x),$$ where $a$ and $b$ are parameters to be estimated and $f$ is a particular functional (e.g. $e^{ax}+b$). The key to both the linear and the logarithmic model is that there is an invertible transformation $$T:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$$ satisfying the equation $$T(y)=ax+b$$ for ANY choice of $a$ and $b$ so that $$y=T^{-1}(ax+b).$$ This transformation, or **linearization** as you're calling it allows you to use linear mean squared error regression to estimate the parameters $a$ and $b$ given samples of $x$ and $y$. Especially desirable extra properties would include not introducing bias given the presence of certain kinds of noise, but you don't indicate that such a bias is much of a concern.

The exact functional form you are trying to match is a bit ambiguous, but for the sake of argument suppose we are trying to fit the data to the functional $$y=a\cdot\arctan(x)+b.$$

It turns out that no such transformation $T$ exists for all choices of the parameters $a$ and $b$. In other words, any attempt to linearize the system in the same way as your code would be guaranteed to NOT reveal a linear dependence for some choices of $a$ and $b$.

However, if you want to expand on your technique, you could allow the introduction of transformations of $x$ and $y$. To make that explicit, if we can find choices of $T$ and $R$ with $T$ invertible which satisfy $$T(y)=aR(x)+b$$ for all choices of $a$ and $b$, then we can estimate $a$ and $b$ with a linear regression and then predict $y$ with the formula $y=T^{-1}(aR(x)+b).$$

In your case, such a transformation is almost handed to you on a silver platter. In particular, choose $R(x)=\arctan(x)$ and $T(y)=y$. Run a linear regression on $y$ vs $\arctan(x)$ to estimate $a$ and $b$, and then you can predict $y$ by applying the regressor to $\arctan(x)$:

```
clf = LinearRegression().fit(np.arctan(x), y)
clf.predict(np.arctan(x))
```

If you had the transformations $T$ and $R$ defined already, these two lines would be replaced in general with something like the following:

```
clf = LinearRegression().fit(R(x), T(y))
T_inv(clf.predict(R(x)))
```

Even without linearizations, the parameters $a$ and $b$ (and more if you have them) can be readily estimated with general minimization formulas. Since you have `scikit-learn` installed, you should have `scipy` on your system as well. As an example, consider the following command:

```
scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
    lambda x, a, b: a*np.arctan(x)+b,
    x,
    y,
    np.ones(2)
)
```

The output might have more information than you want, and you should examine the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for more details, but in general this performs a kind of least-squares regression to estimate your parameters. Working through each of the inputs,

- `lambda x, a, b: a*np.arctan(x)+b` is the function whose parameters you want. The input `x` must be the first argument, and the rest of the parameters follow.
- `x` and `y` should be obvious.
- `np.ones(2)` creates an array of length $2$, representing the parameters $a$ and $b$ in that order. This is your initial guess as to their values. If you have a reasonable guess, you could incorporate it, but for simple functions this should converge anyway without any additional effort.

Comment: Many thanks @Hans Musgrave. Works perfectly!

Comment: Dear @Hans Musgrave, let say now that the $R$ function is similar sigmoid pattern $$R_1(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{(-(x-10)/2)}}.$$, however as model I know only $$R_2(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}.$$. How can find $R_1$ with $R_2$?

Comment: @ecjb This should be asked as a separate question, and on StackOverflow if programming is still the goal. Also, are you trying to find the relationship between $R_1$ and $R_2$, or are you trying to estimate some sorts of parameters again? I.e., do you want to know $$R_1=\frac{1}{1+e^5\sqrt{\frac{1}{R_2}-1}},$$ or do you want to estimate $a$ and $b$ given some data in a functional like $$R=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)}}?$$

Comment: Many thanks @Hans Musgrave. I posted a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854235/how-fit-a-model-with-data-following-asymptotic-sigmoid-pattern